# Celery received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!? - 2 servers connected to same broker

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm stuck.

I have 2 VPS in different locations (one EU, one NA). I sometimes need my Celery task to be executed on an EU server and sometimes on an NA server (because the website displays different information based on location).

So, in my Flask app I created two different tasks that do the same thing:

```
@celery.task(bind=True, name='task_EU')
def task_EU(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    with app.app_context():                                  
        cust_module.handle(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

@celery.task(bind=True, name='task_NA')
def task_NA(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    with app.app_context():
        cust_module.handle(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

Those tasks are called when an action is performed from the admin panel. Depending on what the user has select, I want the task to be executed on server EU or server NA, so I did this:

```
@app.route('/launch-new-project', methods=['POST'])
def launch_new_project():

    arg1 = request.form['arg1']
    arg2 = request.form['arg2']
    arg3 = request.form['arg3']
    arg4 = request.form['arg4']  # EU or NA

    # launch celery task
    if arg4 == 'NA':  # user selected 'NA' from drop-down menu
        task = task_NA.apply_async((arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4), queue='NA')
    else:
        task = task_EU.apply_async((arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4), queue='EU')

    return task.id, 202, {'location': url_for('taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}
```

On the EU VPS, I will launch the queue like so:

```
celery -A myapp.celery worker -Q EU --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=6
```

My broker (I use redis) operates on the same VPS, so no problem connecting to it.

NA VPS command is the same, also connects to the broker that's on the EU VPS.

```
celery -A myapp.celery worker -Q NA --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=6
```

Now when I go to the admin panel, and launch a project while selecting EU from the drop-down -> no problem. The task launches as needed. When I select NA, however, I receive the following error message:

```
Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?
```

I then receive the full content of the message, which is quite cryptic, but it basically contains my arguments. I have no idea how to debug this, why it works on EU and not on NA.

Been stuck on this for days, the solutions on SO didn't help. Please help!

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `-Q` option in your command. i.e.

Change:

`celery -A myapp.celery worker -Q EU --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=6`

to 

`celery -A myapp.celery worker EU --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=6`